# Parameter info not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resharper

I can't get the Edit.ParameterInfo command working, it suddenly stopped working from one day to another.

The only way i can get it to show is when i initially create a method call like this:

```
this.MyMethod(
```

I've tried:

- To trigger it through [Edit > IntelliSense > Parameter Info]
- Using the default Ctrl + Shift + Space
- Resetting key bindings in both VS- and Resharper- settings.
- Adding a new keybinding with no other bindings.

Its unlikely that im the only one out there who have experienced this problem.

Comment: Please add ReSharper version.

Comment: The good news: I have the same issue. The bad news: I'm still searching for a fix. I currently have Resharper 7.1, but I had Resharper 7.0 when it started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed in Resharper 7.1.1: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-336184